# Why my Viewpager is not showing images in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Actually i am new to android development and working on an app and trying to implement viewpager to show the images like carousel in recyclerview but don't know how to set the viewpager in recyclerview onBindViewHolder function to show viewpager the images.
Actually i m trying to implement like this
[image]

**and this is mine app's screenshot**
[image]

so please guide me how can i implement it

my Adapter Class

```
public class RoomsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomsAdapter.RoomsViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;

public RoomsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Rooms> rooms) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RoomsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);
    RoomsViewHolder viewHolder = new RoomsViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RoomsViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Rooms room  = rooms.get(position);
   

    holder.binding.roomsTitle.setText(room.getTitle());
    holder.binding.roomsRent.setText("Rent ₹ " + room.getPrice() + " /month");
    holder.binding.roomsLocation.setText(room.getLocation());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rooms.size();
}

public class RoomsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemProductBinding binding;

    public RoomsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = ItemProductBinding.bind(itemView);
    }
```

}
}

**Actually, i didn't set the viewpager here coz i know how to the set the image view but not any idea how can I set the viewpager in recyclerview to show images from url or drawable.
Please guide me**

Comment: You need to bind the underlying `ViewPager` (if inside the `ItemProductBinding`) with an Adapter having the list of images, which I cannot see you are doing in the `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: yes that is what i am asking you ACTUALLY i dont know how to bind it like if there is a single imageview i can bind it but how to bind a carousel i have no idea

Comment: You can check this tutorial, following that attach the adapter to the ViewPager in onBindViewHolder(). https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-viewpager-with-dotsindicator-in-android/

Comment: ok brother i will try.